# How to achieve a blur effect on navbar?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a blur effect in the background of a navbar component.
If I use a normal blur effect that exist on CSS core, it will not work like I want, so I want some help with this.

Examples:
[image]

Onthe first image, the panel section on the bottom has some "transparent background", but it is not opacity.
On the right side there is a navbar with that blur effect.
I tried to use  CSS blur effect but it makes the menu items not readable.

Comment: Can you attach a sample code of what you did or maybe **codepen**

Comment: Blur means unfocus, what do you meen to blur the navbar, so you meen to unfocus the selected item in navbar or what?

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far. See here on [how to create a better example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't want to "unfocus" the navbar, i want to make the navbar background transparent that we can see the content below it. but this view has to make that messy effect , like when we use the blur effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by a mix of setting opacity to the background color, and adding a blur filter.

For the example below, take a look at `background:rgba(0,0,0,.7)` and `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)`.

For background color, you must use `RBGA` instead of `hex`. Adjust the `.7` at the end to customize opacity. Similarly with blur filter, adjust the `(5px)` for intensity of blur.

```css
.navbar {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);

color:#fff;position:fixed;height:300px;width:500px}
img {position:fixed}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">

<div class="navbar">
transparent black background
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not this effect that I want. The text has to be inside  a box and that box has to have the "blur" effect in the background of his area